# USB 3.0 to dvi adapter on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: drivers, 14.04

I have a USB 3.0 to DVI adapter made by startech and found ubuntu drivers by contacting the chipset manufacturer, but the latest driver that they had for ubuntu was for 12.04. Since I am rather new to ubuntu, I was wondering how difficult it would be to get this driver working on 14.04 or what USB 3.0 to external monitor adapters would be recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install it, odds are it won't break anything regardless.

It should work unless it relies on dependencies that are outdated and no longer available in 14.04.

Comment: I've tried installing it, but the install fails and forces a reboot.

Comment: We need more information to find out what is happening here.  How are you installing it?  Are you doing this via terminal or via the software center?

Could you also post the output of /var/log/syslog after you try to install it.  This may provide useful info.

Comment: I'm installing it with sudo dpkg -i (filename).deb 
I will get the syslog info in a bit, on windows partition for work

Comment: If it's a .sh script then you can just do 

    sudo sh /path/to/file.sh

copy/paste the terminal output here so we can see where thigns are going wrong.

Comment: Ok so I tried running it again and it failed to install. Once it fails i have to go into recovery and use the dpkg clean to be able to boot to my ubuntu desktop. The syslog doesnt really show much but there is an xorg.failsafe.log thatshows AddScreen/ScreenInit failed for driver 0. I went through the deb file and found an auto shutdown script that i tried disabling to see if I could view logs immediately after it fails, but apparently there are unused/redundant files so I need to keep searching. Any advice?

Comment: Going a bit more in depth. Inside the deb file there are 2 main folders, DEBIAN and tmp. Inside Debian there are 3 files, one looks like a package version archive info file then 2 sh scripts. the tmp folder has sub folders KDE and GDM. Inside the GDM(which is what I assume I need) is are 32bit and 64 bit folder. The 64bit one contains 2 files, one called extended and the other tusb_drv.so. I can upload the whole package somewhere if it would help.