# Will USB 3.0 to HDMI video adapter work with Ubuntu 14.04? Other versions?

Tags: usb, hdmi, external-monitor, multiple-monitors

I got Dell Inspiron 5521 notebook with one HDMI port. Currently I use it with Ubuntu 14.04 with one external monitor and with lid open. I dream to close notebook lid and connect the second external monitor.

The notebook doesn't have USB type-C port, only USB 2.0 and USB 3.0 ports.

Will [this device](https://ru.aliexpress.com/item/High-Speed-USB-3-0-To-HDMI-Adapter-Metal-Shell-Male-To-Female-HDMI-Video-Cable/32805127805.html) or similar help me implement my dream?

PS

I've read through [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481351/usb-3-0-to-dvi-adapter-on-ubuntu-14-04) and [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/474608/will-usb-3-0-video-adapter-work-with-ubuntu). the first one could be obsolete. The second relates rather to DisplayPort.

Comment: I multi-task alot so always have laptop lid open plus two external monitors. The exception being movie time where I'll close the lid and move apps to small external monitor and run movie full screen on big external monitor. My point is after an extra screen we seem to develop habits of opening extra windows...

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! We [don't really do hardware recommendations](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16700/can-we-burninate-hardware-recommendation ) or reviews here. You may find out sister site at https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ a better fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the adapter uses a DisplayLink chip, it will probably work. They provide drivers (14.04,16.04,17.10,18.04), installation guides and troubleshooting tips on their [website](https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/684649-how-to-install-displaylink-software-on-ubuntu). AFAIK, you won't be able to use third-party graphics drivers though.

Adapters using Fresco Logic chips will probably not work.

**Closing the lid won't work**. For some reason, applications won't react anymore when the internal display is disabled.

Comment: Just have found this device https://www.startech.com/AV/USB-Video-Adapters/USB-3-to-Displayport-Video-Card-Multi-Monitor-Adapter-2560x1600~USB32DPPRO

Comment: If your monitor has a DisplayPort input, it should work, but it is extremely overpriced IMO. Most adapters, also the cheap ones, use DisplayLink nowadays. You can take a look at [my answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1037292/354663) if you haven't already.